# splitting file with awk command

Tags: bash, awk

I was trying to split a file into a training data set and a test data set. I have this error

> **awk: can't open file -v source line number 1**.

The command line was as follows:

```
awk -v lines=$(wc -l < data/yelp/yelp_review.v8.csv) -v fact=0.80  'NR <= lines * fact {print > "train.txt"; next} {print > "val.txt"}'  data/yelp/yelp_review.v8.csv
```

Anybody enlightens me why it was a problem on macbook?

Comment: try correcting path `data/yelp/yelp_review.v8.csv` to its actual path for example `/data/yelp/yelp_review.v8.csv` once?

Comment: Please create a [mcve], so that everyone can reproduce the issue. Also, don't add tags without any relation to the question, like the two Python tags you used.

Comment: Please add sample input and your desired output for that sample input to your question.

Comment: @RavinderSingh: it could not open the file. it said "awk: can't open file /data/yelp/yelp_review.v8.csv"

Comment: @Ulrich: I will take care next time.

Comment: can you provide the absolute path to the file? I tried it in cygwin and I did not receive error.

Comment: @Kyaw, as mentioned earlier too, try to give complete path of file too in your code once?

Comment: >U said "awk: can't open file /data/yelp/yelp_review.v8.csv" – Kyaw 16 hours ago    <-- here You have a leading slash which makes your path absolute instead of relative.  (which is different than what I see in your code)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well .. miken32 has already identified what went wrong with your first attempt. I can't improve on his explanation of the problem.

My suggestion would be that rather than having `wc` provide your line count, you just do that job with awk itself.  Something like this:

```
awk -v fact=0.8 'NR==FNR{lines++;next} FNR<=lines*fact{print>"train.txt";next} {print>"val.txt"}' "$file" "$file"
```

Though I'd probably write it more like this:

```
awk -v fact=0.8 'NR==FNR{lines++;next} {out="val.txt"} FNR<=lines*fact{out="train.txt"} {print > out}' "$file" "$file"
```

You can decide whether greater elegance is gained by brevity or avoidance of a `next`. :-)

Comment: Thanks a lot. That was really helpful

Answer (score 1):

What does the output from `wc -l < data/yelp/yelp_review.v8.csv` look like? Something like this perhaps?

```
      74
```

So what's going to happen when you drop that into your command?

```
awk -v lines=     74 -v fact=0.80 ...
```

As you can see, this isn't going to parse well. Always quote any variable data you use:

```
awk -v lines="$(wc -l < data/yelp/yelp_review.v8.csv)" -v fact=0.80 ...
```

Awk is smart enough to trim the spaces from the number before using it.